# ExtensionsMetadataGenerator error when upgrading Azure Functions SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I upgraded my azure function sdk from 1.0.14 to 1.0.28 and I get this build error:

```
The ExtensionsMetadataGenerator package was not imported correctly.
```

I can't find any documentation or ways to resolve it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the `1.0.28` function sdk released several day ago, it may have some bugs in it.

Workaround:

Manually adding the
[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator/) nuget package to your project and it will work well.

Comment: This worked for me (a year later). But I was getting warnings about the ExtensionsMetadataGenerator being referenced twice. So I uninstalled this package again and everything worked nicely. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: faced same issue with sdk version 4.0.1. addin this nuget manually worked

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when starting with the Visual Studio Function App template which uses Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.31 and is a .NET Core 2.0 App.

Nuget Package Manager wants to update the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package to version 3.0.2 which it tries to do but the app is still .NET Core 2 and you get the error:

> The ExtensionsMetadataGenerator package was not imported correctly.

To resolve this update the application to .NET Core 3:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update your Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions NuGet package to the newest version that supports your app's version of .NET.

For example, I have a web app running .NET 2.1, I had to rollback the NuGet version to 1.0.36, and the next version (3.0) only worked on .NET 3 and up. After doing this, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator NuGet was not needed at all and all my errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with microsoft.net.sdk.functions  1.0.38 and see the same message but in my case it is a build warning and not an error.

I installed the suggested NuGet package with the version required.  However, I then received 3 warnings:

`The ExtensionsMetadataGenerator package was not imported correctly. Are you missing 'C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets' or 'C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.props'? "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.props" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.props (56,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [D:\myproject.Web\myproject.Web.AzureFunctions\myproject.Web.AzureFunctions.csproj] "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.38\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.targets (64,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [D:\myproject.Web\myproject.Web.AzureFunctions\myproject.Web.AzureFunctions.csproj]`

Worse still my project would not build - it freezes on build with no way to cancel.  The only way to cancel was to do, elevated PowerShell:

`stop-process -name "dotnet"`

To fix this I tried uninstalling the NuGet package but this is not enough as it still seems to be used if it is on the system (even though the project does not reference it?!?).

It is necessary to actually delete the package from package store, i.e. at.

`C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator`

Or an alternative is to comment out the lines:

`<GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadata  SourcePath="$(_FunctionsExtensionsDir)"  OutputPath="$(_FunctionsExtensionsDir)"/>`

From:

`C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.2.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets`

I have no idea if this is safe to do so but it gets rid of the warning message.  I instead opted to just delete the NuGet package and live with the original warning.

Looks like a real mess with microsoft.net.sdk.functions package.